# Infinite sum of normal identical dependent product

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

I'm trying to investigate asymptotic behavior of this sum:

$$\lim_{n->\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nX_iX_{i-1},$$

where $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $cov(X_i, X_i)=1$, $cov(X_i, X_{i-1})=const.$

So, far I managed to find PDF for this product:

$$f_{X_iX_{i-1}}=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\Bigg[\frac{\rho z}{1-\rho^2}\Bigg]K_0\Bigg(\frac{|z|}{1-\rho^2}\Bigg),$$

where $K_0$ is Bessel function, $\rho$ - correlation coeficient.

However, I don't know where to go futher from there.